# SqlCeDataReader Read(); Iterates and Iterates some number of times

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sqldatareader, sqlcedatareader

I am programming an application using SQL Server Compact Edition in which my program inserts some data from somewhere to a local database. My database table has columns like: `username, enterdate, exitdate.`.. and so on.

Now I am trying to read a special row of my data and then add that row to a listview, but when I use the `SqlCeDataReader` and its `Read();` method, it adds duplicate items to my listview. For example if my needed row is at the 9th index of the database, I mean when my desired row for example is in the 9th row of my database when I `SELECT` it using `WHERE` and then I read it, it adds 9 duplicate items with the same row data I need to my listview.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition.

```
Con.ConnectionString = "data source = |datadirectory|\\RoomDataBase.sdf";
Con.Open();
cmd.Connection = Con;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM room WHERE username = '" + user + "'";

SqlCeDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader1.Read() )
{
       dblogger(user + " Entered and WAS in list");
       //my problem happens here that the above line iterates
}
```

`dblogger` is a void that adds a string to a list view

In fact my problem is that the inside of `if{....}` iterates and iterates to number of the number of row in the database

I must tell you that when I `SELECT` data from database using `WHERE` I am sure that only one row matches the criteria, so to be sure about everything, the problem is from the `Read()` procedure.

And I must mention you that this problem either happens when I use `SqlCeResultSet` and then using it `ReadFirst();` .

Special thanks to those who know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your're using the DataReader incorrectly. The read method is used for advancing the the DataReader to the next row. The HasRows property which will tell you if there were any results returned at all.

Try the following:

```
     if (reader1.HasRows)
     {
         dblogger(user + " Entered and WAS in list");
     }
```

Comment: thank you but when i try to use HasRows It says it must be Scrollabel, How Can i change its Option to scrollabe?

Comment: And i tested HasRow Propery with SqlCeResultSet but still i have the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why the IDE would be telling you that. You could try the DataReader's ExecuteScalar method, which would only return the first row of the result set.